# can not save product while adding discount price in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am working with opencart and I am learning right now.

When I add discount price in product and save it then I received notice like :

**Notice: Undefined index: points in /home/eyelens/public_html/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 131Notice: Undefined index: points in /home/eyelens/public_html/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 177Notice: Undefined index: weight in /home/eyelens/public_html/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 177Notice: Undefined index: weight_prefix in /home/eyelens/public_html/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 177Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/eyelens/public_html/admin/index.php:80) in /home/eyelens/public_html/system/library/response.php on line 12**

Here, I got error because my array is full so it can not return point and weight therefor it gives an error. So how can I increase array size ?

Answer (score 0):

**Undefined index** : Even though php does not need variables to be declared first you must have some values in it before using a variable. So it is recommended that you should initialise the variables or use `isset(variablename)` before using the variable.

Inorder to solve **headers already sent** error, you should not print any output before using functions that modify headers like `header() session_start()`

Answer (score 0):

I have write below two variable in php.ini file

**max_input_vars = 30000;**

**max_post_size = 30000;**

and its working perfect.